# How does this `layout` prop get updated without `:layout.sync`?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I don't understand how [vue-grid-layout](https://github.com/jbaysolutions/vue-grid-layout) manages to change `myLayout` in the following [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-grid-layout-updates-without-sync-f79ip):

```
<grid-layout
  :layout="myLayout"
  ....
>
```

I thought that:

```
<MyComponent :layout="myLayout"/>
```

Meant that any changes to `myLayout` here in the parent scope would become changes in in the `layout` prop in `MyComponent`, but `MyComponent` would not be able to change `myLayout`.

Which is what the [sync modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier) was for, so that:

```
<MyComponent :layout.sync="myLayout"/>
```

Would be the equivalent of:

```
v-bind:layout="myLayout"
v-on:update:layout="myLayout = $event"
```

And so without the `.sync`, it would not be possible for a component to change a prop in the parent scope.

But the [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-grid-layout-updates-without-sync-f79ip) demonstrates that [vue-grid-layout](https://github.com/jbaysolutions/vue-grid-layout) manages to change `myLayout` using just `:layout="myLayout"`.

(`:layout.sync="layout"` is used in the [README code for vue-grid-layout](https://github.com/jbaysolutions/vue-grid-layout) and then I understand how it works, but it works without the `.sync`too, which I don't understand.)

What am I missing or misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript objects are passed around by reference, if you must prop an object, clone it and manipulate the clone to avoid it updating the original object.

for example:

```
props: {
    myLayout: Object
},

data() {
    return {
        layout: {}
    }
},

watch: {
    myLayout: {
        handler(myLayout) {
            this.layout = { ...myLayout };
        },
        immediate: true
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple.... vue-grid-layout does actually not follow best practices when it does that, which causes [an issue](https://github.com/jbaysolutions/vue-grid-layout/issues/157) when using vuex.